# Unsatisfied dependency - Error creating Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I followed [this tutorial](https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/use-spring-jms-activemq-jms-consumer-jms-producer-spring-boot) for creating simple JMS related application and I keep getting exceptions (stacktrace pasted below)

I tried looking at other similar threads and in many places it looks like people are asking to add @Repository annotation in the interface but my interface isn't extending any repository.

My code looks like the following:

**JmsClient.java**

```
public interface JmsClient {
    public void send(String msg);
    public String receive();
}
```

**JmsClientImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class JmsClientImpl implements JmsClient{

    @Autowired
    JmsConsumer jmsConsumer;

    @Autowired
    JmsProducer jmsProducer;

    @Override
    public void send(String msg) {
        jmsProducer.send(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public String receive() {
        return jmsConsumer.receive();
    }

}
```

**JmsConsumer.java**

```
@Component
public class JmsConsumer {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${jms.queue.destination}")
    String destinationQueue;

    public String receive(){
        return (String)jmsTemplate.receiveAndConvert(destinationQueue); 
    }
}
```

**WebController.java**

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired
    JmsClient jsmClient;

    @RequestMapping(value="/produce")
    public String produce(@RequestParam("msg")String msg){
        jsmClient.send(msg);
        return "Done";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/receive")
    public String receive(){
        return jsmClient.receive();
    }
}
```

**JmsProducer.java**

```
@Component
public class JmsProducer {
    @Autowired
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Value("${jms.queue.destination}")
    String destinationQueue;

    public void send(String msg){
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(destinationQueue, msg);
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsClientImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsConsumer'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConsumer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAutoConfiguration$JmsTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingJmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration$SimpleConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.javasampleapproach.jms.SpringbootJmsApplication.main(SpringbootJmsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsConsumer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jmsTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAutoConfiguration$JmsTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingJmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration$SimpleConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jmsTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/JmsAutoConfiguration$JmsTemplateConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jmsTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingJmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration$SimpleConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1144) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cachingJmsConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jms/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactoryConfiguration$SimpleConnectionFactoryConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:570) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:546) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:189) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1061) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:567) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

**Added Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.javasampleapproach.jmsactivemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms-activemq</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springboot-jms-activemq</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <description>com.javasampleapproach.jmsactivemq</description>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you post pom.cml or build.gradle?

Comment: @Andronicus  I added the pom.xml above. I am starting it as `Run As -> Springboot App` from Eclipse and getting above errors. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're having is that Spring isn't able to instantiate the `@Autowired` classes you've specified.

The reason it can't instantiate those classes is because it can't find a class that they depend on, as shown at the bottom of your stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

As documented [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19332), this means you need to get the JMS library available for the application to load.

In your pom, you don't specify the version of `spring-jms` you want to use, so it's possible you're getting a version that doesn't contain the library you need.

You can update your pom to get the latest version as described [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms/5.1.5.RELEASE):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Alternatively, you can include the JMS library explicitly by adding the following to your pom (found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1)):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully one of those will allow Spring to instantiate all your beans and start the application.

Comment: Great. I added JMS Library dependency explicitly and it started working.`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>` Thanks